# How to prevent after facebook login redirect url in popup?

Tags: oauth-2.0, yii2

This is my controller.

```
public function actions()
{
    return [           

        'auth' => [
          'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
          'successCallback' => [$this, 'oAuthSuccess'],
        ],
    ];
}


public function oAuthSuccess($client) {

    $name = explode(" ",$userAttributes['name']);
    $existing_customer = Customer::find()
                ->where(['email' => $userAttributes['email']])
                ->orWhere(['id_facebook' => $userAttributes['id']])
                ->one();        

    if(empty($existing_customer)){

        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->firstname = $name[0];
        $customer->lastname = $name[1];
        $customer->id_default_group = 3;
        $customer->username = $userAttributes['id'].'@facebook.com';
        $customer->id_facebook = $userAttributes['id'];
        $customer->email = $userAttributes['email'];
        $password = rand(0000, 9999);
        $auth_key = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString();
        $customer->auth_key = $auth_key;
        $hash = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);
        $customer->password_hash = $hash; 
        $customer->activation_code = $password;
        $customer->active =1;

        if ($customer->save(false)) {      

            $customergroup = new CustomerGroup();    
            $customergroup->id_customer = $customer->id_customer;
            $customergroup->id_group = $customer->id_default_group;
            $customergroup->save(false);                

            Yii::$app->response->redirect(['advanced','email' => $customer->email]);
        }           
    }
```

This is my main.php file.

```
'authClientCollection' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
        'clients' => [
            'facebook' => [                   
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
                'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup',
                'clientId' => '',
                'clientSecret' => '',                    
                'scope' => [
                    'email', 
                    'user_birthday',
                    'user_location', 
                    'user_hometown',                        
                ],
            ],                
        ],
    ],
```

Actually I am doing registration in 2 process.
After user click on facebook button it returns to my second step in popup, But i need it in my site. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

change your `auth  successCallBack`  in action function with the action you desire..

below a sample where successCallback check if the user is a guest if true call the action authenticate otherwise the action connect

```
/** @inheritdoc */
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'auth' => [
            'class' => AuthAction::className(),
            'successCallback' => \Yii::$app->user->isGuest
                ? [$this, 'authenticate']
                : [$this, 'connect'],
        ]
    ];
}
```

After the facebook login you return in your code inside the oAuthSuccess function .. i think the popup you are looking for is inside this function  and is called from this redirect.  if you want somethings others change the bootom part of this function..

```
Yii::$app->response->redirect(['advanced','email' => $customer->email]);
```

Comment: can you please describe about authenticate and connect function?

Comment: These function names are samples.. you must substitute these names with the names of the action you want execute....in the described case

Comment: In you question you use $this 'oAuthSuccess' an action of your controller.. but seems this show a modal that you don't want..

Comment: Actually my registration process is follwed by 2 steps. First step popup is there for facebook login.After that it will return to second step in my site and popup will close.But in my project it returns to second step but in popup window.

Comment: Update your question Showing your controller and specially the  'oAuthSuccess' action

Comment: Hii, Please give me solutions.